# C++ Varaidic Tempate with Eigen, overloading functions with parameter list gives unexpected result

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, eigen

I have been testing C++ templating within Eigen and have come across a problem while developing when using tempates and templated parameter lists.
As per the following example, the "Function 2" is printed for all calls - even though the 3rd and 4th call perfectly match the prototype. It seems that the templated parameter list takes precedence due to an ambiguity.
Now the interesting part is that this only happens when matrices are wrapped in "Eigen::MatrixBase", if I send matrices directly it is not a problem. But this would not be optimal for the expression templates being used.

Could someone explain the reason for this when using MatrixBase and what could be a workaround?
I understand that giving one function a different name will do the trick, but then the function will loose generality. Is there a better way to fix it?

Thank you for your time!

*Minimal example showing the effect:*

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, 2, 2> QType;
typedef Eigen::Matrix<float, 1, 1> UType;

template <typename... ParamsType>
void fun(const Eigen::MatrixBase<QType> &Q,
         const Eigen::MatrixBase<UType> &U,
         const ParamsType & ...params)
{
  cout << "Function 1" << endl;
}

template <typename... ParamsType>
void fun(const Eigen::MatrixBase<QType> &Q,
         const ParamsType & ...params)
{
  cout << "Function 2" << endl;
}

template <typename... ParamsType>
void fun2(const QType &Q,
          const UType &U,
          const ParamsType & ...params)
{
  cout << "Function 1" << endl;
}

template <typename... ParamsType>
void fun2(const QType &Q,
          const ParamsType & ...params)
{
  cout << "Function 2" << endl;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QType Q = QType::Random();
  UType U = UType::Random();

  int param = 0;

  fun(Q);
  fun(Q, param);
  fun(Q, U);
  fun(Q, U, param);

  fun2(Q);
  fun2(Q, param);
  fun2(Q, U);
  fun2(Q, U, param);

  return 0;
}
```

*Output:*

```
Function 2
Function 2
Function 2
Function 2

Function 2
Function 2
Function 1
Function 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that `UType` is not the same as `MatrixBase<UType>`, but it inherits from it. That means passing `U` as a variadic parameter is closer to the function header (sorry for not being able to reference the corresponding section in the standard). See this simplified example which also illustrates the difference:

```
#include <iostream>

class A {};
class B {};
class C : public A { };
class D : public B { };

template<typename... P>
void fun(const A&, const B&, const P & ...p)
{
    std::cout << "funAB\n";
}

template<typename... P>
void fun(const A&, const P & ...)
{
    std::cout << "funAP\n";
}

int main()
{
    A a;
    B b;
    C c;
    D d;
    fun(a,b); // funAB
    fun(c,d); // funAP, because d only inherits from B
}
```

If you explicitly want "Function1" to be called when `UType` is passed, just write that as the parameter (as in your `fun2` implementation).

Comment: Ah now I understand, thank you! So one must give up the expression templates (no MatrixBase) to get around this? Or have different function names.

Comment: The `MatrixBase<>` base class is essentially a hack to allow static polymorphism (look up "curiously recurring template pattern" (CRTP), if you are interested in details). If you know exactly what class you want, there is no need to use it (i.e, there is no benefit making a method accept `MatrixBase<MatrixXd>&` instead of plain `MatrixXd&`).

Comment: Thank you, but I would like to point to the Eigen documentation on [passing matrix parameters](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox-devel/TopicFunctionTakingEigenTypes.html) where it explicitly states, in the first paragraphs, that the matrix will be evaluated to a temporary matrix, hence loosing the efficiency of the expression templates and creating temporaries when not using `MatrixBase`.

Or are you saying that this does not happen? Have I misunderstood the documentation?

The code I am developing works on the assumption that all sizes are known at compile time, I have no dynamic matrices.

Comment: Yes, it will be evaluated into a temporary if the matrix is not exactly of type `UType` or `QType` in your example. But that is independent of whether you take `UType` or `MatrixBase<UType>`. If you want to avoid temporaries, you need to accept `MatrixBase<Derived1>, MatrixBase<Derived2>` where `Derived*` are template parameters of the function. If you want to specialize on the size of the arguments, you need to somehow hide that into a helper struct (see how `operator=(const MatrixBase<OtherDerived>& m)` of `QuaternionBase` is implemented for an example.